# Pass operator as function template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have to overload the basic arithmetic operators for some very complicated objects I've made.  So far, I've successfully implemented `operator*`; now I need `operator+`, etc.  The code for `operator*` is very large, but the only difference between `operator*` and `operator+` will be one line where I use `+` instead of `*` on some complex numbers.  This line will be inside of a loop that gets called many many times, so I want it to be efficient, which would seem to imply no function pointers.  (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

This seems like a perfect use for templates.  But I'm at a loss as to the correct syntax.  I'm thinking something like this inside the `ComplicatedObject` class definition:

```
template <typename ComplexBinaryOp>
ComplicatedObject BinaryOp(const ComplicatedObject& B) const {
  // Do lots of stuff
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<OneBazillion; ++i) {
    // Here, the f[i] are std::complex<double>'s:
    C.f[i] = ComplexBinaryOp(f[i], B.f[i]);
  }
  // Do some more stuff
  return C;
}

inline ComplicatedObject operator*(const ComplicatedObject& B) const {
  return BinaryOp<std::complex::operator*>(B);
}

inline ComplicatedObject operator+(const ComplicatedObject& B) const {
  return BinaryOp<std::complex::operator+>(B);
}
```

This question is related: ["function passed as template argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument).  But the functions passed as the template arguments are not operators.

I've fiddled with the syntax every way I can think of, but the compiler always complains of bad syntax.  How should I do this?

## Edit:

For clarity, I include the complete solution in terms of my code above, along with the additional generalizations people may need:

```
template <typename ComplexBinaryOp>
ComplicatedObject BinaryOp(const ComplicatedObject& B) const {
  // Do lots of stuff
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<OneBazillion; ++i) {
    // Here, the f[i] are std::complex<double>'s:
    C.f[i] = ComplexBinaryOp()(f[i], B.f[i]); // Note extra ()'s
  }
  // Do some more stuff
  return C;
}

inline ComplicatedObject operator+(const ComplicatedObject& B) const {
  return BinaryOp<std::plus<std::complex<double> > >(B);
}

inline ComplicatedObject operator-(const ComplicatedObject& B) const {
  return BinaryOp<std::minus<std::complex<double> > >(B);
}

inline ComplicatedObject operator*(const ComplicatedObject& B) const {
  return BinaryOp<std::multiplies<std::complex<double> > >(B);
}

inline ComplicatedObject operator/(const ComplicatedObject& B) const {
  return BinaryOp<std::divides<std::complex<double> > >(B);
}
```

Comment: `std::complex` is a class template, so you need `std::complex<double>`. But even then, `complex<T>::operator*` and `complex<T>::operator+` are *member functions*. You can't just pass them around without an instance of `complex<T>` to operate on.

Comment: Post errors you are getting.

Comment: +1 for interesting question. I also found this question -- [c++ pointers to operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176895/c-pointers-to-operators) relevant and interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `std::plus<std::complex>` and `std::multiplies<std::complex>` are what you're looking for, but I'm not 100% sure I understand your question (is your code snippet within a class you aren't showing us?)

Comment: +1, I think this is what the OP is looking for too, but it should be `plus<complex<double>>` and `multiplies<complex<double>>`

Comment: @Praetorian: so `plus` and `multiplies` can be used without specifying the `std` scope?

Comment: +1 Yes, this looks like what I want, alright (though @Praetorian is right).  But I can't quite figure out how to use these functions.  The compiler objects to my line `ComplexBinaryOp(f[i], B.f[i])`.  Any help on that?

Comment: @keelar That's not what I meant. `std::complex` is a class template, so it needs to be specialized for a type. `std::plus<std::complex<double>>` and so forth. (Although you *could* use `plus` and `multiplies` unqualified as long as you qualify `complex` because of [ADL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup))

Comment: @Praetorian: sorry for my pickyness.  Your point is clear.  I was thinking about using the same notation as the original answer might be better.

Comment: @me `ComplexBinaryOp()(f[i], B.f[i])` does the job.  Note the extra parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Pass the function at runtime:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename ComplexBinaryOp>
ComplicatedObject BinaryOp(const ComplicatedObject& B, ComplexBinaryOp op) const {
  // ...
    C.f[i] = op(f[i], B.f[i]);
  // ...
}

// functor wrapping member function pointer
BinaryOp(B, std::mem_fn(&std::complex<double>::operator+));

// standard-issue functor
BinaryOp(B, std::plus<std::complex<double>>());
```

Or pass it at compile-time:

```
// or another floating-point type
typedef double (*ComplexBinaryOp)(double, double);

template <ComplexBinaryOp op>
ComplicatedObject BinaryOp(const ComplicatedObject& B) const {
  // ...
    C.f[i] = op(f[i], B.f[i]);
  // ...
}

// non-member function
template<class T>
std::complex<T> add_complex(const std::complex<T>& a, const std::complex<T>& b) {
  return a + b;
}

// non-member function pointer
BinaryOp<add_complex<double>>(B);
```

I believe you can do the same with member function pointers as well by changing the definition of `ComplexBinaryOp`.

Comment: These look like useful possibilities.  I'll try things out and get back to you.  Thanks!

Comment: Turns out my original syntax works just fine, after replacing `std::complex::operator*` with `std::multiplies`, etc.  Yours also work, but they strike me as less simple.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, that works too. You do have to say `ComplexBinaryOp()(foo, bar)` to actually get the functor instance, though. That can just as well be done inside or outside as in my first example.